# How to disable backend access to Azure RESTful services?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-management-api

I am planning to use Azure REST API management.

Among other things to standardize the security when calling the restful services. However I can't seem to figure out how to prevent access to the actual REST API as in to (lock the actual service away behind the REST API management).

What's the best practice around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

- [Mutual Certificate Authentication](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates/) between Azure API Managament and your private API.
- Basic Authentication on your private API and setup these details in Azure API Management.
- Via a VPN / private network connection (this is currently not available but is coming).